# Invalid double While Dividing the String

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error While Dividing the String FormatException : Invalid double

```
double planAvg = (double.parse(planlist[pos].total_amt).toString() / double.parse(planlist[pos].total_weight).toString()).toStringAsFixed(2);
```

This is how i implement

```
planAvg == ""
    ? SizedBox()
    : Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
       child: Text(
         "Avg : " +
         planAvg,
         style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 17,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
         ),
        ),
      ),
```

if anyone can please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's why you are getting the error:

1. The `toString()` method converts the double value into a String value. The `/` operator cannot be used with Strings.
2. Since you are using `toStringAsFixed(2)` at the end, it returns a String value. Hence, you cannot store it inside a double variable.

Try this:

```dart
String planAvg = (double.parse(planlist[pos].total_amt) / double.parse(planlist[pos].total_weight)).toStringAsFixed(2);
```

Comment: ```planAvg = double.parse(planlist[pos].total_amt.isEmpty?"0":planlist[pos].total_amt) /
        double.parse(planlist[pos].total_weight.isEmpty?"0":planlist[pos].total_weight);```

Comment: Ah, okay. You also wanted to check if the value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping transform to double and back and again.

Assuming this is a String: `planlist[pos].total_amt`

```
String planAvg = (
    double.parse(planlist[pos].total_amt) / double.parse(planlist[pos].total_weight)
).toStringAsFixed(2);
```

So, what you want to do is transform both of them to double, make the division operation and then back to String.

Instead, if you want a double as return, just:

```
double planAvg = double.parse(planlist[pos].total_amt) / 
                 double.parse(planlist[pos].total_weight);
```

Comment: Yes I want them into string

Comment: But I am still having an error says "format Exception invalid double"

Comment: With the first snippet of code, you shouldn't have the error.
Maybe the content of planlist[pos].total_amt and total_weight is not valid to translate in double, try to visualize their values to debug the error

Comment: right now i edited my code can you just go through it

Comment: And also planlist[pos].total_amt and planlist[pos].total_weight are but coming dynamicly and both are String

Comment: first: you are declaring planAvg as a double, but you assign to it a String.
second: even if you assign them dynamically, probably the value in them is not a correct string to transform in double! for example, "2," would not be a valid double.
Visualize their values!

Comment: Okay Thanks for your guide line